# Celery as demon

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, celery

I have made project using `celery` as task processor, `RabbitMQ` as broker queue with `flask` as app. when I run `flask` app and I also start celery using below command.

```
$ celery -A app.app worker --loglevel=INFO --concurrency=10 -n
```

Now I have deployed `flask app` using `apache2 wsgi`. So my question how to make celery work without using command as `demon`.

Answer (score 0):

It is all covered in the documentation in the [Daemonization](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html) section.